# How to maintain pixel when zooming into SVG canvas?

Tags: svg, zooming, stroke

I've built a frontend tool for zooming in/out of an SVG canvas, but when I zoom, any 1px strokes increase in width (visually). Is there a svg setting that will ensure that 1px strokes remain 1px (visually) when zoomed? I remember reading about it somewhere, but can't find the resource.

Comment: i think the whole point is that it is Scalable vector graphics... so zooming is just like using a magnifying glass - ll things will get bigger proportionally.

Comment: You can add `vector-effect="non-scaling-stroke" ` attribute to the path?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Try to add `vector-effect="non-scaling-stroke"` attribute to the path. Check [HERE](http://www.w3.org/TR/SVGTiny12/painting.html#NonScalingStroke) for details. Im guessing that's what you want?